# How to use functional types or lambdas as type for Kotlin's context receivers?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, kotlin-context-receivers

```kotlin
package yamin

typealias Foo = () -> Unit

fun main() {
    bar {
        baz()
    }
}

fun bar(foo: Foo) {
    foo()
}

context(Foo)
fun baz() {
    //
}
```

I tried to use a lambda type for the context of a function, which seems to be fine at this point but when I tried to call that function in that context, or at least what I think is that context I'm failing, and Kotlin's compiler is showing me this error for `baz()`:

```kotlin
No required context receiver found: Cxt { context((yamin.Foo /* = () -> kotlin.Unit */)) public fun baz(): kotlin.Unit defined in yamin in file Main.kt[SimpleFunctionDescriptorImpl@7b5e305f] }
```

Maybe I misunderstood Kotlin's context receivers or I'm expecting something that it's not designed for. I just want to create a function that can only be called in certain context and in this example only in a certain lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is right now, your `baz` can be called like this:

```
val someFoo: Foo = {}
with(someFoo) {
    baz()
}
```

By using `with`, I bring an instance of `() -> Unit` into the context, so `someFoo` becomes a context receiver with which I can call `baz`. In `baz`, I can then access this `someFoo` by using `this@Foo`. This is how context receivers are supposed to work.

If you want `baz` to only be able to be called in `bar`'s lambda, `bar`'s lambda needs to provide the context receiver using a receiver parameter, similar to how `with`'s lambda is declared `T.() -> R`.

```
object Foo

fun main() {
    bar {
        baz()
    }
}

fun bar(foo: Foo.() -> Unit) {
    Foo.foo()
}

context(Foo)
fun baz() {
    // ...
}
```

I changed the actual context here to just an `object`, because as far as I can see, there is nothing special about `bar`'s lambda. Of course, if you want, you can make it provide extra information to `baz` by changing `Foo` to a class that does contain data.

Note that this does not prevent someone from doing:

```
with(Foo) {
    baz()
}
```

It is quite hard to prevent against this without adding another layer outside of `bar`, like:

```
// note that bar is no longer a global function
import bar.Foo.Companion.bar

class Foo private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun bar(foo: Foo.() -> Unit) {
            Foo().foo()
        }
    }
}

context(Foo)
fun baz() {
    // ...
}
```

You can also do something simple like this prevents it from happening from outside the package:

```
sealed interface FooInterface

private object Foo: FooInterface

fun bar(foo: FooInterface.() -> Unit) {
    Foo.foo()
}

context(FooInterface)
fun baz() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a function that can only be called in a certain scope, give the function itself a receiver. Instead of `typealias Foo = () -> Unit`, you would use something like `typealias Foo = MyReceiver.() -> Unit`.

You can do this with a regular extension receiver, but it's also possible with context receivers.

Here's a simple version that works for me:

```kotlin
typealias Foo = BarScope.() -> Unit

fun main() {
    bar {
        baz()
    }
}

object BarScope

fun bar(foo: Foo) {
    BarScope.foo()
}

context(BarScope)
fun baz() {

}
```